# Is there a way to remove the banner for myself from the site?

Tags: discussion

The banner that says "do not share your persnoal medical information..." seems to be permanent.

How can I remove it for myself?

Comment: Just so you know, that banner is much longer and much more legalese than we asked for. It was obviously written by the SE legal department and we weren't particularly happy with it either. We asked, but they won't change it.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot remove it through any option on this site. It's a good reminder and having it always present makes it clear what new users see.

If you wanted, you could write a [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) - websites work by your browser rendering a display for you based on code sent to you from a server. Userscripts edit that code for you only, changing the way a site appears to you without any change on the server.